# thunderbird addon that searches for HTML in email

Tags: search, thunderbird

I often need to search for specific details about an html-formatted email. As an example, I'd like to be able to filter by presence of an image source name (`<img src="...">`). However, even though I'm looking right at an email *"View >> Source"* and see it in an email, when I search for that string, it comes up empty.

Some TB add-ons have discussed this problem, but I've seen none that successfully find matches. Thoughts? (I'm otherwise stuck either viewing source one-by-one, or using command-line `grep`, back-tracking to a specific message id, and grabbing them manually in TB.)